# iOS contraints to center an image is not working

Tags: ios, autolayout

I added 2 constraints to center an UIImageView within a UIView.
The constraints are to center it vertically and horizontally.
But for some reason it is not centering.

Note that the container UIView has constraints of margins for the top, bottom, left, right.

Why the centering is not working?
Is it possible that the UIImageView itself needs an explicit size?

Unfortunately this is all done via Storyboard, so I have no snippets to share.

Comment: either give horizontal and vertical  constraints or give top and bottom. Don't give both. you could share the images of your storybaord, and the image that explains the issue.

Comment: Keep in mind that an image is not necessarily centered in its image view. Give the image view a colored background and run your app so that you can see where the image view really is. You might want to show us a screen shot of what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try below code, It is working fine.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myImageView = UIImageView()
    myImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
    myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // set contentMode to center image
    myImageView.contentMode = .Center

    // if you want some specific heigh and width of myImageView then uncomment below Two line to add the height & Width constraints.
    // view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myImageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200))
    // view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myImageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200))

    // if you do not set the height and width constrints then myImageView size depends on actual size of image.
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myImageView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myImageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can share screenshot like which type of Layout needed.

You can set image view as Horizontal and Vertical like this. check below image,

[image]